# startActivity for result does not called on fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, photo

I'am try to use start Activity for result to pick photo from gallery but it  does not called on fragment

I checked most  solutions but no one work for me 
please help me

```
 newsImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image*//*");
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,GALLERY_INTENT);
            }
        });
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if(requestCode==GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Uri uri=data.getData();
            StorageReference filePath=mStorage.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    downloadUri=taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).load(downloadUri).fit().centerCrop().into(newsImg);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    publishBtn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: the code you are using would be helpful

Comment: @cgomezmendez OK

Comment: Your problem is in your gallery intent. You have not used it properly. Try doing this, check this out in my edited answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this and then find out, before giving my answer I would suggest you to be please do some research or search the exact thing in short form like you want to use the use the **gallery intent**, just use the **image picker** in android or gallery intent in android. For going from the fragment we use the **getContext()** rather than using ActivityIntent like MainActivity.this.

For Calling the startActivity for result do like this :

```
private final int REQUEST_CODE = 1

class ImagePicker extends Fragment{
   /*here we are calling the start activity for result
   supposing you know how to use the gallery intent so just giving you 
   the answer what you want */

   Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), YourClass.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
 }
```

And in **onActivityResult()** you get the result in the same Fragment or Activity after finishing this.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //get your gallery image uri data here
        }
}
```

Hope it helps and please refer to this link to read more about the how to get the data in the same Activity.

[About startAcitivityForResult in android](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example)

Hope that helps! Thanks

**EDITS**

Since your code seems fine for gallery intent but I think there is problem with your gallery intent. Try this also and see if it works.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, RESULT_CODE;
```

Here specifically **I have used the inten.setType("image/*")** and one more thing, make this simple, **do not use getActivity.startActivityForResult()** just make it simple, startAcitivityForResult() will also work fine and use **getContext() despite of doing getActivity().getApplicationContext()**. Try amending this thins things and tell me whether it works or not!

Comment: I tried to use the same code that i used in fragment  in Activity and everything work fine but when I put the code in fragment the app stoped

Comment: thank you.  I solved it the problem cauesd by                 
 using intent.setType("image*//*");
insted of                 intent.setType("image/*");

Comment: @hudaOlayan if you did it then please upvote and mark the answer as right by hitting the tick mark and mark it as correct! :)